# How to search the .kitchen.yml attributes

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen

I want to search the hostname with

```rb
searchnode = search(:node, "zookeeper:true")
```

Want to get output `Hostname.fqdn.com` as node but i am not getting it. Maybe I don't know how to access the attribute.

```yaml
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  environments_path: test/integration/default/environments
  client_rb:
    environment: stg

  always_update_cookbooks: true

verifier:
  name: inspec

platforms:
  - name: centos-7.2

suites:
  - name: Hostname.fqdn.com
    run_list:

          - recipe[test-cookbook::test]


    data_bags_path: "test/integration/default/data_bags"


attributes: {zookeeper: "true"}
```

Comment: You explicitly want to search, right? I assume that you know how to access the current `node`'s attributes..

Comment: No i dont know current node attributes via test kitchen

Comment: `node['zookeeper']` is really new to you? Please read the tutorials on [learn.chef.io](https://learn.chef.io).

Comment: Not sure, if I get your real problem.

Comment: No you are given answer that is indentation error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.kitchen.yml` is not valid, as the top-level `attributes` section is ignored. You should move this below the `suite`'s elements (indentation matters with YAML!):

```yaml
suites:
  - name: Hostname.fqdn.com
    run_list:
      - recipe[test-cookbook::test]
    data_bags_path: "test/integration/default/data_bags"
    attributes: {zookeeper: "true"}
```

Then, your `search` should find this node. You can use `kitchen diagnose` to see the resulting attributes.

If you want to mock other nodes in test-kitchen, you can place JSON files containing the node definitions in `test/integration/nodes` (as used in [this cookbook](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/backuppc/tree/130382e665d473b13911185773c6db0a207a979c/test/integration/nodes); can be configured via [`node_path`](https://docs.chef.io/config_yml_kitchen.html)). You can then use search to "discover" other nodes based on their attributes or run lists.

Comment: While copying i have copied    run_list:
      - recipe[test-cookbook::test]

Comment: Thank you so much yes (indentation matters with YAML!)